# My WebApi works fine on Visual Studio but doesn't work on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5, asp.net-web-api2

There are bunch of the same questions I could find in SO and over the internet. However non of them were a solution to my issue (At least the solutions I have seen so far). So I need your help.

I have created a `WebApi` with the following listings which it works fine when I run it from Visual Studio. But it doesn't work when I publish that to the IIS of my own machine.

It gives me  *HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found*  error.

- Operating System: Windows 7
- IDE: Visual Studio 2013
- IIS: version 7.5

**This is the `system.webServer` and `applicationSettings` part of the `web.config`:**

```
          <system.webServer>
            <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
            <handlers>
              <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
              <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
              <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
              <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*"
     type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
            </handlers>
          </system.webServer>
          <applicationSettings>
            <SampleAspNetWebApi.Properties.Settings>
              <setting name="AuthorityAddress" serializeAs="String">
                <value>https://localhost:44333/core</value>
              </setting>
              <setting name="SampleAspNetWebApi_SmsPanel_SMS" serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://something.com/smsws/soap.asmx</value>
              </setting>
            </SampleAspNetWebApi.Properties.Settings>
          </applicationSettings>
```

**This is the Routing Map:**

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

**Finally this is my controller which I have created just for testing purpose:**

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Just for test";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

[image: Application Advance settings]

[image]

Comment: [HttpGet] is useless if you're using public method with name starts with `Get`.

Comment: Only showing web.config is useless. You need to show your IIS settings like site bindings.

Comment: @LexLi See my update and please tell me what other details are required. Thanks in advance

Comment: That's probably enough. 1) Try to register ASP.NET 4 on IIS, using `aspnet_regiis.exe`. It is well documented so you should be able to search and know how to do it. 2) Enable Failed Request Tracing to track down the 404 error if it remains.

Comment: I could find the problem however, I can't figure out the reason. When I use visual studio deployment tool I have the issue but when I copied the `bin` folder manually into the folder path IIS refers to, the problem solved. Wierd huh? I had registered ASP.NET in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your IIS/Websits's hostname, you need to add some hostname e.g. mytestapi (the last picture you shared from your IIS settings)

then add this into your system's host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts):

127.0.0.1    mytestapi

then test your api from this url:

http://mytestapi/api/yourapicontroller